# Format extracted text

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to extract just the text from the p element in a div. The issue I have is when I extract the text it does not preserve the line breaks.

Here is the code I am using

```
 $('div.post-content p').text();
```

There are multiple p tags within div so I want to preserve them in their own class.

For example each sentence is a different p tag and shows like this currently: Some text. Some other text. Some more text.

I want it to look like this:

Some text.

Some other text.

Some more text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using html() you can have all tags, but in HTML. Is possible for you?

Comment: I just need the text and not the tags but would like to keep the line breaks so that it preserves the fact that each p tag is its own paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/e924u/)***

Each paragraph is going to inherently be its own area. You probably want to maintain that level of separation. You could do this storing them in an array using `.each`

```
var paragraphs = [];
$('div.post-content p').each(function(){
 paragraphs.push($(this).text());
});
```

If you wanted to put these together, say in a single p tag, you could then later do this

```
$("#result").html(function(){
 return paragraphs.join("<br>"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the HTML elements you need to use the `.html()` method not the text method. Because text would only retrieve the text and not the margins and paddings.

For that you can use this:

```
$('div.post-content p').html();
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the text with the tags attached, is there  a way to remove the tags but give the line breaks?

Comment: You can try something like, getting the text of each of the paragraph, and then adding a few line break between them! :)